# android - filter listview inside popupwindow

Tags: android, listview, android-popupwindow

I am not able to **filter listview** which is inside a Popupwindow.

It fails with an exception

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@150769 is not valid; is your activity running?
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:679)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1378)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:1154)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:1121)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.positionPopup(AbsListView.java:5665)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.showPopup(AbsListView.java:5651)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTextChanged(AbsListView.java:6095)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8187)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4483)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4337)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:89)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4312)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.setFilterText(AbsListView.java:1944)
```

I display the PopupWindow as:

```
popupWindow.showAtLocation(getWindow().getDecorView(), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

Popup Layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:hint="" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can you provide pointers?

Comment: provide your adapter code for listview?

Comment: I resolved this issue by using dialog instead of popupwindow

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are showing your popup is shown too early. Use showatlocation in runnable like below

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        pwindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
}, 100L);
```

Comment: Issue is list filtering inside popup. I am able to show popup. But when list filtering happens it tries to show another popup which raises exception.

Comment: Try using runnable if it works or else post your code, will figure out issue.